# Does a wave have inertia?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, momentum, wave-particle-duality, inertia

In de Broglie hypothesis, particles have wave nature. The question is does this wave have inertia? If so is it represented in the corresponding wave equation?

Answer (score 2):

Let's first address the general question--do "waves" of any kind have (or can they have) inertia? I suppose here by "inertia" you mean "resistance to changes in velocity." This is certainly true of waves in, say, water--you've certainly felt resistance to your hand if you sweep it through water to make a wave; the destructive force of a tsunami is a more extreme example of the force a wave can transmit.

Even in classical electromagnetism, where the waves (light) are massless, they still have inertia. Consider, for a very direct example, a solar sail which reflects light from a source and acquires momentum from the rebounding light--we wouldn't expect this to happen if light waves had no inertia, since in that case presumably we could easily change their direction with no resistance.

Now, do quantum "matter waves" have inertia? This a more subtle question, because the wave should not be viewed as a "spread out" particle, but rather a probability amplitude for the particle to be measured as present at a particular point in space.

However, I think it should be clear that these waves do have inertia, by considering collision problems, just as we did for the previous two cases. We know that when two particles collide, they must conserve momentum. For instance, it is not possible that two particles of equal mass collide head-on and then both move in the same direction afterwards, and furthermore we know that this collision is extremely well-modeled quantum mechanically by Schrodinger's wave equations.

To get a more direct and mathematical answer, let's consider another definition of inertia, which is that an object has inertia if its velocity (and thus its momentum) remains unchanged unless acted on by an external force. For a massive, non-relativistic, particle, the Hamiltonian is given by:
\begin{equation}
H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)
\end{equation}
Here V(x) is our external potential ("force" is a difficult quantity to work with in quantum mechanics), $p$ is the momentum operator, and $m$ is the mass of the particle. Suppose there is no external force, so $V(x) = 0$ (or any constant really). Then the rate of change of the momentum operator using the Heisenberg picture (equivalent to the more traditional Schrodinger wave picture) is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \mathrm{d}{p}}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{i}{\hbar} \left[ H , p \right] = 0
\end{equation}
This is because the momentum operator is only commuting with $p^2$, and operators always commute with their own squares. Therefore, momentum is unchanging, and we can see that the "principle of inertia" is indeed respected by the equations of quantum mechanics. This occurs in the equations essentially by the fact that the free-particle Hamiltonian commutes with momentum, and therefore if the particle is subject to this Hamiltonian the momentum will not change.

Answer (score -4):

[TDSE](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/imgqua/seq4.gif)

[TISE](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/imgqua/seq13.gif)

Here you have the time dependent and independent Schrodinger wave equations, respectively.  These relate to the energy of particles, but the trident symbol, Psi is representative of the actual wave equation I believe you are referring to.

While De Broglie and schrodinger and others like them do describe particles as behaving like waves, they are referring primarily to probability functions, or wave equations describing where a particle is likely to be found.  Meaning, in a given space, the particles and the "paths" they move in can be represented by waves, where you have crests (areas of high probability) and troughs (areas of low probability).

In short, particles CAN have mass and thus COULD have inertia, but the wave equation themselves do not as they are merely a representation of probability.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to downvote; there are several basic misunderstandings of QM in this answer. It's not "crests" and "troughs" that are high/low probability, as probability is given by the square of the wavefunction. It is not the case that "most particles move at or near the speed of light," and relativistic considerations are not the source of the uncertainty principle. You cite Schrodinger equations and say the equation doesn't have mass, but the $\hbar^2 / 2m$ term is precisely the mass and reflects the massive dispersion relation.

Comment: @zeldredge Sorry for the misunderstanding in the last statement, I meant the wave equations do not have inertia, but of course they have mass as you pointed out.  I cited the Schrodinger equations as they are the ones I am most familiar with, but in retrospect they may not have been the best to cite as they are used for finding particle energy.
Nonetheless, the symbol Psi represents the probability wave function as seen: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/1ce07ac1bf7488ce9e2d4dee730c68cde4fe29d4
This is the square of Psi and PSi*, yes but still uses wave and troughs.

Comment: Also, I believe relativistic considerations are EXACTLY the source of the uncertainty principal, because particles move near the speed of light their positions are uncertain.  But please, if I am completely incorrect, cite your sources. I am not trying to speak absentmindedly.

Comment: It is better to put the equations inline using [mathjax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks! That's actually very helpful.

Comment: @Garrettfromhp I'm sorry, but this simply not true. Wikipedia's derivation of the generalized uncertainty principle should convince you that it derives from the fact that position and momentum operators don't commute; see also Sakurai's "Modern Quantum Mechanics" Ch 1, p 55-56. In the same book, Sec 2.3 shows that the principle holds for all states of a harmonic oscillator--including the ground state, which has zero expectation value for momentum. They simply aren't related.

Comment: @Garrettfromhp you should also consider the results of innumerable atom trap/matter wave experiments which work by cooling atoms to their motional ground state; this requires them to have little to no velocity at all so that they will have a significant De Broglie wavelength

Comment: @zeldredge Indeed, I could concede that the uncert. princ. is not due to near light speed of particles.  After researching further, I see it comes from the size nature of particles. It just happens that many particles travel at or near light speed, i.e. photons.
However, getting back to the OQ, I still hold that the wave equation cannot have inertia as it does describe a probability function.  The WE is a construct for our own interpretation of the wave-like nature of particles.